# what is clientArray and how to access to data clientArray

Tags: jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

i see `clientArray` in this code

```
 if (id && id !== lastSel) {

                        grid.saveRow(lastSel, true, 'clientArray'); 

                        grid.jqGrid('restoreRow', lastSel);
                        grid.jqGrid('editRow', id, true, null, null, 'clientArray');
                        lastSel = id;
                        //}  
                    }
```

what is a `clientArray` and how to access data `clientArray`?

thanks for help me.

Comment: http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing look for clientarray here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when write this code

```
grid.jqGrid('editRow', id, true, null, null, 'clientArray');
```

data not send to server and just sore data in grid